# Как ограничить максимальное кол-во строк в запросе из базы в Hibernate?

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate

Подскажите кто пожалуйста, как в хибернейте сделать выборку не всех значений в базе,  а лишь некоторых ? Не совсем могу понять. 
Есть данные в таблице (их 4 млн строк).
Сам код выглядит так:

```
@Override
public List<UserStatisticDto> findGroupedByUser(final PageInfoDto pageInfo) {
   final Query query = buildSortQuery(pageInfo.sort, StatisticEventEntity.FIND_GROUPED_BY_USER_QUERY, StatisticEventEntity.FIND_GROUPED_BY_USER);
    query.setFirstResult(0);
    query.setMaxResults(20);
    List<UserStatisticDto> list = toUserStatisticDto(query.getResultList());
    return getSubList(list, pageInfo);
}

private Query buildSortQuery(final SortInfoDto[] sort, final String sortQuery, final String nonSortQuery) {
        Query query;
        if(sort != null && sort.length > 0) {
            String queryString = sortQuery;
            query = getEntityManager().createQuery(queryString);
        } else {
            query = getEntityManager().createNamedQuery(nonSortQuery);
        }
        return query;
    }

    private List getSubList(List list, final PageInfoDto pageInfo){
        int startIndex = (pageInfo.pageNumber) * pageInfo.pageSize;
        int lastIndex = startIndex+ pageInfo.pageSize + 1;
        if (lastIndex > list.size()){
            return list.subList(startIndex, list.size());
        }
        return list.subList(startIndex, lastIndex);
    }
```

Класс PageInfoDto:

```
public class PageInfoDto implements Serializable {
    public int pageNumber = 0;
    public int pageSize = 20;
    public SortInfoDto[] sort;

    public PageInfoDto() {
    }

    public int getFirst() {
        return this.pageNumber * this.pageSize;
    }
}
```

Этот код работает отлично для другой базы с таблицей у которой записей 61 000.
При разворачивании другой базы с таблицей в которой 4 млн записей, он виснет минут на 10 и потом достает.

Я понимаю он пытается сразу достать эти 4 млн и только потом выводит мне их по 20 штук на страничку html.

Подскажите пожалуйста, как быть, как заставить его не доставать сразу 4 млн записей, не могу понять..

Сам запрос HQL в коде такой:

```
public static final String FIND_GROUPED_BY_USER_QUERY = "select e.user, e.eventType, count(e) from StatisticEventEntity e WHERE e.college.deleted=false group by e.user, e.eventType";
```

Всем заранее спасибо!

Comment: Работу с базой организуете сами или реализуете data-интерфейс spring-a (CrudRepository, например)? А то есть ещё интерфейс PagingAndSortingRepository, который может вытаскивать данные постранично.

Comment: @Bakhuss спринга нет, вместо него google-guice. Цепочка такая:  - UsersStatisticsResource - StatisticService - StatisticServiceBean - StatisticEventDao - StatisticEventDaoBean - и в нем уже сам метод, который я описал выше. (в нем StatisticEventEntity и там запрос в базу HQL)

Answer (score 3):

Надо использовать:

```
Query.setMaxResults(int maxResults); //аналог limit в SQL
```

Если он не задан, то результаты будут неограничены.

Иногда бывает еще полезно использовать:

```
Query.setFetchSize(int fetchSize); //задает размер буфера, который подкачивается за 1 раз - работает не со всеми СУБД
```

Comment: Дело в том, что у меня указан query.setFirstResult(0) и query.setMaxResults(20), но все равно не работает.  Но Query.setFetchSize(int fetchSize) я сделать не могу, он недоступен у query, вы наверно для jdbc имели ввиду

Comment: Тогда у вас батенька сам запрос тормозит. Запустите ваш запрос из командного клиента Postgres и попробуйте применить к нему [explain](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-explain.html) - почти наверняка у вас проблема с `where` или `sort` по неиндексированному полю

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо за совет, попробую, потом отпишусь

Answer (score 1):

Используйте Spring Data JPA. Там есть реализация PageRequest(это и реализует паджинацию внутри кода).

А в реализации самой JPA есть такое решение:

```
return getEntityManager()
           .getCriteriaBuilder()
           .createQuery(query)
           .setMaxResults(limit)
           .getResultList();
```

Comment: К сожаление не могу использовать Spring Data JPA. В проекте его нет, переписывать не очень хочется. Но спасибо за ваш ответ

Comment: Тогда, как вариант в CriteriaBuilder можно задавать лимит